# Best way to handle URLs in a multilingual site in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, internationalization, multilingual

I need to do a multilingual website, with urls like

```
www.domain.com/en/home.aspx for english
www.domain.com/es/home.aspx for spanish
```

In the past, I would set up two virtual directories in IIS, and then detect the URL in global.aspx and change the language according to the URL

```
Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim lang As String
    If HttpContext.Current.Request.Path.Contains("/en/") Then
        lang = "en"
    Else
        lang = "es"
    End If
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(lang)
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(lang)


End Sub
```

The solution is more like a hack.  I'm thinking about using Routing for a new website.

**Do you know a better or more elegant way to do it?**

edit: The question is about the URL handling, not about resources, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I decided to go with the new ASP.net Routing.
Why not urlRewriting? Because I don't want to change the clean URL that routing gives to you.

Here is the code:

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Code that runs on application startup
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
End Sub


Public Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)
    Dim reportRoute As Route
    Dim DefaultLang As String = "es"

    reportRoute = New Route("{lang}/{page}", New LangRouteHandler)
    '* if you want, you can contrain the values
    'reportRoute.Constraints = New RouteValueDictionary(New With {.lang = "[a-z]{2}"})
    reportRoute.Defaults = New RouteValueDictionary(New With {.lang = DefaultLang, .page = "home"})

    routes.Add(reportRoute)
End Sub
```

Then LangRouteHandler.vb class:

```
Public Class LangRouteHandler
     Implements IRouteHandler

  Public Function GetHttpHandler(ByVal requestContext As System.Web.Routing.RequestContext) As System.Web.IHttpHandler _
      Implements System.Web.Routing.IRouteHandler.GetHttpHandler

    'Fill the context with the route data, just in case some page needs it
    For Each value In requestContext.RouteData.Values
        HttpContext.Current.Items(value.Key) = value.Value
    Next

    Dim VirtualPath As String
    VirtualPath = "~/" + requestContext.RouteData.Values("page") + ".aspx"

    Dim redirectPage As IHttpHandler
    redirectPage = BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath, GetType(Page))
    Return redirectPage

  End Function
End Class
```

Finally I use the default.aspx in the root to redirect to the default lang used in the browser list.
Maybe this can be done with the route.Defaults, but don't work inside Visual Studio (maybe it works in the server)

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim DefaultLang As String = "es"
    Dim SupportedLangs As String() = {"en", "es"}
    Dim BrowserLang As String = Mid(Request.UserLanguages(0).ToString(), 1, 2).ToLower
    If SupportedLangs.Contains(BrowserLang) Then DefaultLang = BrowserLang

    Response.Redirect(DefaultLang + "/")
End Sub
```

Some sources:
  * [Mike Ormond's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/mikeormond/archive/2008/05/14/using-asp-net-routing-independent-of-mvc.aspx)
  * [Chris Cavanagh’s Blog](http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2008/04/25/systemwebrouting-with-webforms-sample/)
  * [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

1. Use urlrewriteing.net for asp.net webforms, or routing with mvc. Rewrite www.site.com/en/something.aspx to url: page.aspx?lang=en.
   UrlRewriteing.net can be easily configured via regex in web.config. You can also use routing with webforms now, it's probably similar...
2. with webforms, let every aspx page inherits from BasePage class, which then inherits from Page class.
   In BasePage class override "InitializeCulture()" and set culture info to thread, like you described in question.
   It's good to do that in this order: 1. check url for Lang param, 2. check cookie, 3. set default lang
3. For static content (text, pics url) on pages use LocalResources,or Global if content is repeating across site. You can watch videocast on using global/local res. on www.asp.net
4. Prepare db for multiple languages. But that's another story.

Answer (score 0):

I personnaly use [the resources files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9.aspx).

Very efficient, very simple.

Comment: uhh? We are talking about handling the urls and mapping to a specific language.

Comment: Yes, but with the resource files, you don't have to map urls to languages, thus, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

UrlRewriting is the way to go.

There is a good article on MSDN on the best ways to do it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx

Comment: I do't like UrlRewriting because it changes the URL

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a tangent, but I'd actually avoid doing this with different paths unless the different languages are completely content separate from each other.

For Google rank, or for users sharing URLs (one of the big advantages of ‘clean’ URLs), you want the address to stay as constant as possible.

You can find users’ language preferences from their browser settings:

```
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture
```

Then your URL for English or Spanish:

> www.domain.com/products/newproduct

Same address for any language, but the user gets the page in  their chosen language.

We use this in Canada to provide systems in English and French at the same time.

Comment: I do not agree. 1. Your content will never be spidered in both languages. 2. You cannot share a url in a specified language.

Comment: So in your initial example should it be www.domain.com/es/casa.aspx for Spanish?

Comment: No, the name of the url will be the same (in fact, is the same file) but the content and meta tags will be in spanish so people can find searching for spanish content or english content. BTW, Home will be more like Inicio than Casa :)

Comment: You're taking away control from the user. bad. Check out what Apple do. Sub directories for countries and lang. And Apple's products are as consistent across countries as you can get. It sounds nice to dynamically show content in the user's language, but in a practical sense?

Comment: How is that taking control away from them? It's a few clicks to change their language settings if they want to, and the right language is effortless.

Comment: Many keep the default settings as US Eng. You're in Canada, so u prob. realize that 90% don't change their system to En-Canada. Also, people can't bookmark the site in their language. Use site.com/ca/fr, site.com/ca/en, & site.com/us/. There's a reason big companies like MS & Apple do it this way.

Comment: Why's that a problem - they'll get a few minor spelling differences for en-US rather than en-CA (or just en), same as if they have fr-FR instead of fr-CA. Why would they need a bookmark in their language - surely their language makes most sense as a setting on their OS?

Answer (score 0):

To do this with URL Routing, refer to this post:

[Friendly URLS with URL Routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266719/url-routing-how-to-handle-spaces-and-illegal-characters-for-friendly-urls#271568)

Answer (score 0):

Also, watch out new IIS 7.0 - URL Rewriting. Excellent article here http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/496/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing/

I liked this part 
**Which Option Should You Use?**

1. If you are developing a new ASP.NET Web application that uses either ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET Dynamic Data technologies, use ASP.NET routing. Your application will benefit from native support for clean URLs, including generation of clean URLs for the links in your Web pages. Note that ASP.NET routing does not support standard Web Forms applications yet, although there are plans to support it in the future.
2. If you already have a legacy ASP.NET Web application and do not want to change it, use the URL-rewrite module. The URL-rewrite module allows you to translate search-engine-friendly URLs into a format that your application currently uses. Also, it allows you to create redirect rules that can be used to redirect search-engine crawlers to clean URLs. 
   http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/496/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing/

Thanks,
Maulik.