# Generate a URL with URL Routing in Webforms

Tags: c#, url, routes, url-routing

I know in the MVC Framework, you have the Html Class to create URLs:

```
Html.ActionLink("About us", "about", "home");
```

But what if you want to generate Urls in Webforms?

I haven't found a really good resource on the details on generating URLs with Webforms.

For example, if I'm generating routes like so:

```
Route r = new Route("{country}/{lang}/articles/{id}/{title}",
                  new ArticleRouteHandler("~/Forms/Article.aspx"));
Route r2 = new Route("{country}/{lang}/articles/",
                  new ArticleRouteHandler("~/Forms/ArticlesList.aspx"));

Routes.Add(r);
Routes.Add(r2);
```

How would i generate URLs using the Routing table data.

### How do I generate URLS based on my routes?

eg. /ca/en/articles/123/Article-Title without

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you say, ASP.NET MVC offers you a set of helper methods to "reverse lookup" the RouteTable and generate a URL for you. I've not played with this much yet but as far as I can see you need to call the GetVirtualPath method on a RouteCollection (most likely RouteTable.Routes). So something like:

```
Dim routedurl = RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(context, rvd).VirtualPath
```

You need to pass the RequestContext and a RouteValueDictionary. The RouteValueDictionary contains the route parameters (so in your case something like county="UK", lang="EN-GB" etc. The tricky part is the RequestContext as this is not part of the normal HttpContext. You can push it into the HttpContext in your IRouteHandler:

```
requestContext.HttpContext.Items("RequestContext") = requestContext
```

and then restore it again in your IHttpHandler (aspx page) when required:

```
Dim rvd = 
  New RouteValueDictionary(New With {.country = "UK", .lang = "EN-GB"})
Dim routedurl = 
  RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(context.Items("RequestContext"), rvd).VirtualPath
```

Apologies for responding to a C# question in VB, it was just that the ASP.NET routing site I had to hand was in VB.NET.

Comment: That's okay. I'm bilingual... and sometimes I even speak Pascal.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for the answers.  TO add to this, here is what I've done:

### In Global.asax

```
RouteValueDictionary rvdSiteDefaults 
    = new RouteValueDictionary { { "country", "ca" }, { "lang", "en" } };

Route oneArticle 
    = new Route("{country}/{lang}/articles/a{id}/{title}",
        rvdSiteDefaults,
        rvdConstrainID,
        new ArticleRouteHandler("~/Articles/Details.aspx"));

Routes.Add( "Article", oneArticle);
```

### Create Url from Article object

```
public static string CreateUrl(Article a) {
    // Note, Article comes from Database, has properties of ArticleID, Title, etc.
    RouteValueDictionary parameters;

    string routeName = "Article"; // Set in Global.asax

    parameters 
      = new RouteValueDictionary { 
         { "id", a.ArticleID }, 
         { "title", a.Title.CleanUrl() } 
        };
```

CleanUrl() [returns a URL Friendly name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266719/url-routing-handling-spaces-and-illegal-characters-when-creating-friendly-urls#271568).

```
    VirtualPathData vpd = RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(null, routeName, parameters);

    string url = vpd.VirtualPath; 
    return url; // eg. /ca/en/1/The-Article-Title
}
```

TaDa!

Comment: Great, I needed exactly this to generate URLs from inside controllers. :)

It also appears you do not need to name your routes: simply add a "controller" and an "action" string to your parameter dictionary and call GetVirtualPath without routeName. Works all the same.

Comment: Thanks this helped me overcome a problem I had with Response.RedirectToRoute.
http://forums.asp.net/t/1631283.aspx

Comment: @armstrongest with your approach can we able remove the parameter from the URL `Ex:`  `{Title}` and i am passing  `Title` and `Id`   in routevaluedictionary in `MapPageRoute` , so can we able to do it?

Comment: @Webruster I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but yes, you don't need `{title}` in the URL, it's there mostly for SEO purposes. but you'd have to make the parameter optional or create a route without it in there. It's been a while since I've worked with .Net MVC and this is now 8 years old, so there are probably more modern ways of doing this.

Answer (score -1):

Hyperlink hl = new Hyperlink();
hl.Text = "click here";
hl.NavigateUrl="~/Forms/Article.aspx";
MostlyAnyControl.Controls.Add(hl);

as for putting it in a list... either (1) loop / iterate, or (2) Linq to XML.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I wasn't clear.  I know how to generate Hyperlinks. I'm trying to generate friendly urls, based on the rules I have set in my Routing Table.