# Generating User-Friendly URLs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, friendly-url

Is there a standard way / C# library to convert a string into a user friendly uri in order to use it in a RESTful MVC environment?

StackOverflow does this, for example "èòà" are converted to "eoa", question marks are removed while dots, commas and brackets are replaced with "-" and so on.

Any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Stackoverflow Archive:

- [Making strings URL Friendly **(eg: convert Montréal to Montreal)**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611787/making-strings-url-friendly-eg-convert-montr233al-to-montreal)
- [How do I generate a friendly url in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37809/how-do-i-generate-a-friendly-url-in-c)
- [Safe characters for friendly url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695438/safe-characters-for-friendly-url)
- [How can I create a friendly URL in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217960/how-can-i-create-a-friendly-url-in-asp-net-mvc)

For more: Google "[site:stackoverflow.com friendly url .NET C#](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+friendly+url+.NET+C%23&aq=f&oq=&aqi=&fp=dMlfxuRvj0I)"

Comment: The code-project link was good, don't know why you removed it ;)