# MVC route localization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

While playing around with localization using [Matt Hawley's](http://blog.eworldui.net/post/2008/10/ASPNET-MVC-Simplified-Localization-via-ViewEngines.aspx) approach. I wonder if someone has figured to localize routes. I can do this using global resources per site. But when I would try to make it a users choice (so users can switch between languages) the architecture does not allow it because the routes are mapped at application startup and not at session level. Do I have to provision a site per language? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

No sure if this is what are you asking, but in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82380/best-way-to-handle-urls-in-a-multilingual-site-in-asp-net) I present a solution using asp.net routing (the same used in MVC) for dealing with routes and languages.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create one site per language.

What I would try to do is use the default controller to catch all requests. Then translate the controller name + action into a base language and then redirect the route appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is also a help on this topic

http://haacked.com/archive/0001/01/01/internationalized-urls.aspx